# I remember seeing somewhere that clerics are proficient with their deities favored weapon. Is this true?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, cleric

I remember seeing somewhere, but I'm not sure where I remembered seeing it, where children who are raised as clerics are trained in the use of their deities favored weapon.

Does anyone else remember anything like this from anywhere? If so, where?

Comment: Although not 3.5, in pathfinder a cleric gets proficiency with their deities favored weapon.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [the 3.5 SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/cleric.htm) in the class description for the Cleric:

> **Weapon and Armor Proficiency**
>
> Clerics are proficient with all simple weapons

Which means that normally, Clerics are proficient with simple weapons only. But a Cleric who chooses the War domain becomes proficient in the deity's favored weapon.

> A cleric who chooses the War domain receives the Weapon Focus feat related to his deity’s weapon as a bonus feat. He also receives the appropriate Martial Weapon Proficiency feat as a bonus feat, if the weapon falls into that category.

A Cleric without the War domain does not gain that proficiency.

Comment: This answer is not 100% correct, as a Cleric with the war domain will not be proficient automatically with their deity's favoured weapon if that weapon is an exotic weapon.

Answer (score 3):

I house rule that Clerics can use their deity's favored weapon. It isn't like they are getting free weapon focus unless they take the war domain. You have much more power issues from Clerics using Righteous Might, Divine Metamagic, and Miracle then whether or not they are using a Quarterstaff, a Mace, a Longbow, or a Longsword.

Comment: So true. So so true.